# Which one is better in terms of Speed and memory usage or simply best practice

Tags: javascript

I have a function with a lot of constant variables inside. Would it be better to store these variables in a Hash-map (it would be a complicated one) (it would have hash-maps inside the Hash-map. Or several if, else if clauses. In terms of readability they're about the same. But What I'm worried about is the memory taken and the speed of the app. This is a extremely simplified version of the problem :

```
function myFunction(data) {
    var a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
    if(data == value1) {
        a += 3;
        if(value1Fetched) {
           b += 6;
           c +=2;
           d +=1;
        }
    } else if (data == value2) {
        a += 1;
        if(value2Fetched) {
           b += 4;
           c +=9;
        }
    }
return a+b+c+d;
}
```

Obviously there are way more flags and values (and Data is a Hash-map too)

version 2 :

```
function myFunction(data) {
    var a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
    var myHash = {
        value1: {
            a: 3,
            b: 6,
            c: 2,
            d: 1            
        },
        value2: {
            a: 1,
            b: 4,
            c: 9,
            d: 0  
        }
    };
    a += myHash[data][a];
    if(isFetched(data)){
        b += myHash[data][b];
        c += myHash[data][c];
        d += myHash[data][d];
    }
return a+b+c+d;
}
```

Sorry for the messy (pseudo)code, i tried to make it as readable as possible.
This has been haunting me for days and everyone at work has a different opinion.

Comment: what does `?` mean without `:`?

Comment: @NinaScholz Oh sorry. This is a typo. Infact, I was doing them inline and then decided to go for an if

Comment: @Anthony N. Just a side note. If you are going to do a bunch of if statements with the data value, you may be better off doing a switch statement. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: your variables are not initialized, only declared. so `a += myHash[data][a];` does not work, unless you like to get `NaN`.

Comment: if you could declare myHash outside of myFunction, you'll use less ram and CPU on garbage collection. as is, that object must be created every execution, even though it doesn't have any dynamic or closure-sourced values, which means it can live outside and you can use one copy on all function invocations.

Comment: @ShadowCodex The problem is that it's not 1 value in the if. the actual format is : if(myHash.value1 != undefined)

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm sorry again, I know that but this is like pseudo code so i might have other errors. It's just about the principle and not the syntax. But i'll fix it anyway. Thanks ^^

Comment: @dandavis In fact I am working with an object and this function is a method inside my object. So yeah the Hash-map would be defined in the object itself.

Comment: alright, good. one last point: instead of repeating dots, assign as much object to a var as you can. ex: instead of many`myHash[data][X]` , try `var mhd=myHash[data]; ... mhd[a]  ... mhd[b] ...`

Comment: @dandavis oh yeah excellent point.The access time would be much faster. Thanks!

Comment: js is pretty smart under the hood these days, so i don't know that it would be a whole lot faster, it might, but it's a lot less code to write, debug, and ship to the client, and can be a bit more readable as well. in older browsers, read IE, it will be measurably faster.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the extensibility of the second question far outweighs any possible (and unlikely) performance issues. You can even change that structure on the fly if needed, or have multiple instances for two environments where the mapping turns out different.

It might be slower for examples as small as the one you posted, but it sounds like the actual might have a great many entries, in which case using a map lookup has O(log(n)) complexity rather than O(n) (hope I have those terms correct! Been a while since college). Large JSON objects (string-maps) are not uncommon in JavaScript, in fact you often work with them for the libraries and browser features in common code.

Comment: I completely agree but In my problem, I have a lot of different flags and the function also behaves differently in some cases (depending on the hash-map which can also have flags inside that would also alter the behavior of the function). I end up having to write way to many if statements anyway. So i decided to go with all If's to be homogeneous.